# Is there any female hadith narrator other than Aisha(R. A)

Tags: hadith, women

Is there any hadith narrator other than Aisha that is woman.

And can you give some of there hadith. Of female narrators.

Comment: There are many you should rather focus on what you exactly mean by "woman". See for example [Are there any books written by female scholars](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37757/are-there-any-books-written-by-female-scholars). Alone in the 6 known books include 2764 hadith are transmitted by women in 2539 these women are from among the Sahabah: Around 40 woman from the Sahabh have transmitted hadith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are several female narrators of hadith apart from Aisha. Below I give names and link to one hadith narrated by each.

Hafsa (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5916), Um Salama (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:850), Um Habiba (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5339), Maimuna (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:249), Zainab bint Jahsh (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3346), Safiya (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3101), Sauda (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6686).

Asma bint Abu Bakr (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6593), Um Hani (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6158), Um Al-Fadl (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1658), Um Atiyya (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5342), Fatima bint Qais (https://sunnah.com/muslim:1482), Umm Hisham (https://sunnah.com/muslim:873b),

There are many more, in Musnad An-Nisa Imam Ahmad has compiled hadith from around seventy women.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are, you can find hadeeth in English at https://sunnah.com/ and in the beginning it says who the narrator is.

Comment: I want an female hadith narrator other than Aisha (R. A)